# Compiz Makes Dock, and panel disappear

Tags: compiz

I remember clicking something like "Disable Unity Desktop." As soon as I did that, the dock disappeared, and I cannot access the top panel (where I can click gear icon, volume, network, etc.) I enabled "Wobbly Desktops" and then something else, and I accidentally clicked the wrong button "Disable Unity Desktop. My desktop is all blank, how can I get back the dock and such?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, I recomend un-checking "Disable Unity Desktop"

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked numerous times, each with a different title.

Follow these instructions **(read all instructions first)**:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.
2. Execute these commands:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   ccsm
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> sometimes) to get back to the graphical display where there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager window.
4. Enable the 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin'
5. Never disable this plugin again

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/176889)

Comment: err, broken link... and if it was asked before the correct behavior is flagging as duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard. From there, you can reset Unity by entering in these commands, each followed by enter:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
sudo reboot
```

After hitting enter for the following command, you'll need to enter your password, then the computer will reboot. When you log back in, you should be back in Unity. The whole process will look something like this:

[image: How to Reset Unity]

Comment: [Please see here on why this is not the preferred way to reset unity](http://askubuntu.com/a/202020/45659). This is the simpler solution, but unity-tweak-tool provides a cleaner method. *Full Disclosure:* I am the developer of unity-tweak-tool, and I am shamelessly advertising it.